# How to display Json object in chart js consisting of lists created using Django rest framework in angular application

Tags: python, json, angular, django-rest-framework, chart.js

I am sending a json object created using Django rest framework to display in chart using Chart js in angular application.

**Json:**

```
[{"data": "[5908, 3793, 3002, 2049, 1907]", "labels": "['0005', '0022', '0003', '0135', '0061']"}]
```

In angular app, I am calling the api to get the above json and trying to display in the chart as below:

```
import { PieData } from '@modules/charts/models/charts.model';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
   selector: 'sb-charts-pie',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
   templateUrl: './charts-pie.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['charts-pie.component.scss'],
})
export class ChartsPieComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('myPieChart') myPieChart!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
chart!: Chart;

url = 'http://localhost:7000/products';
httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' });
Data: number[] = [];

Labels: string[] = [];

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient
        .get<PieData[]>(this.url, {
            headers: this.httpHeaders,
        })
        .subscribe(result => {
            result.forEach(x => {
                this.Data.push(x.data);
                this.Labels.push(x.labels);
                console.log(this.Data);
            });
            this.chart = new Chart(this.myPieChart.nativeElement, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                    labels: this.Labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data: this.Data,
                            backgroundColor: 'blue',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Model class for PieData is as below:

```
export class PieData {
  data!: number;
  labels!: string;
}
```

Console Log for this.Data and this.Labels is showing as below:

```
  ["[5908, 3793, 3002, 2049, 1907]"]

  ["['0005', '0022', '0003', '0135', '0061']"]
```

Django rest framework (server side) code as below:

model.py:

```
class Products(models.Model):
      data = models.TextField()
      labels= models.TextField()
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Products
    fields = ('data',
              'labels'
              )
```

view.py:

```
def products(request):
    labels = []
    data = []

    products = GetSQLData('db', 'query')
    for product in products:
        labels.append(product.ProdID)
        data.append(product.TotalCount)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        objects_list = []

        d = collections.OrderedDict()
        d['data'] = data
        d['labels'] = labels
        objects_list.append(d)

    products_serializer = ProductSerializer(objects_list, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(products_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

How to display the above data in chartjs? Please help!!

Comment: It looks like a server serialization bug to me.  You aren't returning lists of of numbers, you are returning a string of a list of numbers, and the second one is a string of a list of strings.  You could run JSON.parse again on those to get a real array in the client, but you probably should fix it on the server.

Comment: @cjd82187 I updated the question with server side code. Can you plz suggest what needs to be changed to send the correct Json format? I am using OrderedDict to serialize the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When assigning your data to `Data` and `Labels`, you should parse the string into an `array` using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Instead of this...

```
result.forEach(x => {
  this.Data.push(x.data);
  this.Labels.push(x.labels);
});
```

do this:

```
result.forEach(x => {
  this.Data = JSON.parse(x.data);
  this.Labels = JSON.parse(x.labels);
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but while parsing this.Labels, getting error like ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1